# For-comprehensions of dynamic depth in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am writing a code that needs to generate all combinations of integer sequences which are (element-wise) within bounds of two other integer sequences. The code will be probably more readable than the above explanation:

```
def combinations(startingCounts: List[Int], endingCounts: List[Int] ) = for(
  a <- startingCounts(0) to endingCounts(0);
  b <- startingCounts(1) to endingCounts(1);
  c <- startingCounts(2) to endingCounts(2)
) yield List(a, b, c)

combinations(List(0,7,3), List(1,7,5)) 
//^returns Vector(List(0, 7, 3), List(0, 7, 4), List(0, 7, 5), List(1, 7, 3), List(1, 7, 4), List(1, 7, 5))
```

The above code works as expected, but it has two problems:

- It only works correctly with lists of a certain length. This isn't really an issue with my use-case, but in general it is.
- The code length is proportional to the list length I need to take care of. In my case the length is 6 and I have a for-comprehension with 6 generators.

My question is: what is the best way of implementing the same function in a way that it works with all "bound list" lenghts? By "best" I mean correct, [simple enough](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hoare_Property), and preferably not (much) slower than the original.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
def combinations(startingCounts: List[Int], endingCounts: List[Int] ) : IndexedSeq[List[Int]] = {
  if(startingCounts.isEmpty)
    IndexedSeq(Nil)
  else 
    for{
      ns <- combinations(startingCounts.tail, endingCounts.tail)
      n <- startingCounts.head to endingCounts.head
    } yield 
      n :: ns
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my initial solution. It looks OK, but I wonder if it can be done better.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

type SLInt = IndexedSeq[List[Int]]
def combinations2(startingCounts: List[Int], endingCounts: List[Int] ): SLInt = {
  @tailrec
  def inner(acc: SLInt, startingCounts: List[Int], endingCounts: List[Int]): SLInt = {
    (startingCounts, endingCounts) match {
      case (sh :: st, eh :: et) if (sh <= eh) => {
        val newAcc = for(
          ls <- acc;
          last <- (sh to eh)
        ) yield (last :: ls)
        inner(newAcc, st, et)
      }
      case (Nil, Nil) => acc
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
    }
  }
  inner(IndexedSeq(List()), startingCounts.reverse, endingCounts.reverse)
}

combinations2(List(0,7,3), List(1,7,5))
//res3: SLInt = Vector(List(0, 7, 3), List(1, 7, 3), List(0, 7, 4), List(1, 7, 4), List(0, 7, 5), List(1, 7, 5))
```

The order of the results is different, but that doesn't make a difference. I am performing the `List.reverse` to avoid using `List` append operation and to use prepend instead, which should be constant time.